# Simple calculator in Ruby

Tags: beginner, ruby, calculator

I wrote a calculator in Ruby. These are the rules:

- Write the first number, in a new line the      arithmetic operator, and in another line the last number.
- Use + for addition, - for subtraction, * for multiplication and / for division.

Implementation:

```
val1 = gets.to_i
sym = gets.chomp
val2 = gets.to_i

def addition(val1, val2)
    return val1+val2
end

add = addition(val1, val2)

def subtraction(val1, val2)
    return val1-val2
end 

sub = subtraction(val1, val2)

def division(val1, val2)
    return val1/val2
end 

div = division(val1, val2)

def multiplication(val1, val2)
    return val1*val2
end

mult = multiplication(val1, val2)

if sym == "+"
puts add
elsif sym == "-"
puts sub
elsif sym == "/"
puts div
elsif sym == "*"
puts mult
else puts "error"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. For the future, the title of a question should be a brief summary of the code. I changed it for you this time, feel free to further improve it if you want. To make the most out of your post, please read [ask].

Comment: Do you have anything particular you think needs improvement? What aspects are you looking for help with?

Comment: Well I know it works, but I would like to know if my code is functional, I wonder if there isn't an easier or better way of doing the same thing.
And also I don't know how I could make it work on more than two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating all the function returns and then checking which one the user input why not just run the function after checking the users input.

For example instead of

```
add = addition(val1, val2)
if sym == "+"
    puts add
```

Why not

```
if sym == "+"
    puts addition(val1, val2)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! It also solved the problem J H found. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose X is any val1 value, and 0 is supplied for val2. Then there are three classes of calculations that fail:  X + 0, X - 0, X * 0.
The difficulty is that you evaluate division(X, 0) when there is no need to do so, and you raise a div-by-zero exception.

You might put the four functions into a map, with +-*/ characters as the keys, and dispatch in that way, rather than using `if` statements.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, thanks.By map you mean the map method? I don't really know how to do that, I googled it but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: put four function objects into a dict